# C# Console. Huge output lag for some characters

Tags: c#, encoding, output, lag

I need to refresh the console content multiple times every second.

When special characters like ▒ and other pseudographic elements appear in the output, the output slows down very much depending on the percentage of filling the screen with these special characters.

I tried to change the encoding here and there, but returned back to Unicode, because I need characters that are not in the standard ASCII, although perhaps the extended ASCII would have been enough for me if I could fix the problem with the output delay.

By the way, I also changed the fonts back and forth, but when displaying question marks instead of special characters, the output delay does not disappear anywhere.

The FPS value drops from 60-70 to 10-12 when displaying special characters.

There used to be times when all sorts of roguelikes and even RayCast FPS like Doom were drawn with special characters and nothing slowed them down.

I am using Visual Studio 2019 .Net C#
Console Application

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you able to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, are you able to provide what .Net SDK version you're using (i.e. .NET Framework, .NET Core (1/2/3)).

Comment: In general you will not get good perfoormance in a console bc all "Write" operations refresh the buffer. You want to grab [Console.OpenStandardOutput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.openstandardoutput?view=netcore-3.1) and play aroud with it.

Comment: Sup, im using .Net framework 4.8, not .Net Core.

Comment: At the end of each step i have just a string. Im setting a cursor at 0,0 and write it so my console window fills with new frame. My console window size and buffer size equals to length of my string